# The usage of “cplusplus” keyword in Omnet++

Tags: omnet++

I was trying to understand the usage of "cplusplus" keyword in Omnet++, what is the "cplusplus" keyword uses in Omnet++? If I don't use of cplusplus keyword, what problems are occurred? For example, in the following code:

```
cplusplus 
{{
    typedef struct _payload
    {
        int fileId;              //if file request
        char fileData[4096];    // if file data response
        
    } payload;
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cplusplus` keyword is used in MSG file to mark a native C++ code (usually a structure that is used for definition of a message). It is described in
[OMNeT++ Simulation Manual](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:msg-defs:cplusplus-blocks).